# htaccess: how can I minimize there rules

Tags: mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I using htaccess mod_rewrite for a product site.

when a product is going to be add,

I create a hierarchy of product categories  in url
like

```
1) http://www.example.com/Place-an-ad/Cars/Mazda/mazda-y/mazda-y-2/  4 levels here
2) http://www.example.com/Place-an-ad/Books/Science/                 2 levels here
3) http://www.example.com/Place-an-ad/Realestate/Apprtments/small/   3 levels here
```

categories can be 2, 3 or 4 level

I put this in htaccess, eventhough I do not want to duplicate.

```
RewriteRule ^Place-an-ad/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/?$ new_ad.php?c1=$1&c2=$2&c3=$3&c4=$4 [NC,L] # for 4 level categories
RewriteRule ^Place-an-ad/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/?$ new_ad.php?c1=$1&c2=$2&c3=$3 [NC,L]  # for 3 level categories
RewriteRule ^Place-an-ad/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/?$ new_ad.php?c1=$1&c2=$2 [NC,L] # for 2 level categories
RewriteRule ^Place-an-ad/(.*)/(.*)/?$ new_ad.php?c1=$1 [NC,L] # for 1 level category
```

Can any one short this, so that all categories can be handled by one rule.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be much easier to do this sort of url rewriting using whichever server side language (e.g. PHP) your site is written in. If you have these urls stored in a database you can add a table column to store the name of the script that should be executed when each url is called.

Comment: Thank you for suggestion, i leave the rules as it as, as there is no issue other than redundancy.

Comment: Solution: RewriteRule ^Place-an-ad/?([^/]*)/?([^/]*)/?([^/]*)/?([^/]*)/? new_ad.php?c1=$1&c2=$2&c3=$3&c4=$4 [NC,L]  This is what i required. Here  /? make evan Slash it self optional, and ([^/]*) is translated as "Not Slash or Nothing" making all 4 backreference optional.  Now i replace 4 rules with this single rule.